# How to use Facebook share FBML button on a page loaded via Ajax?

Tags: ajax, facebook, fbml

I have a chunk of content that I load via [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), and on that page I have a FBML share button.  I also tried it without the FBML and just used the hyperlink and script tag.  When I load the content directly, the share button loads fine, but when I load it via Ajax, the button doesn't show up.  Any ideas on how to get the Facebook Share button working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to invoke [FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree) after your content has been inserted.  This will cause the Facebook JS libraries to scan for XFBML tags and render them.

Comment: It appears that this command has been updated to [FB.XFBML.parse()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) (original answer by [talentedmrjones](http://stackoverflow.com/users/259805/talentedmrjones))

Answer (score 2):

use this javascript function ;)

```
fb_sharepro_render()
```

Comment: Why is this better than the JavaScript SDK's `FB.XFBML.parse()` method?

Comment: i put another solution that will work also for users using the facebook share button with ajax content without the javascript SDK check this issue http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=53105